# Custom Javascript in Checkout - Agreements Modal

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5, billing-agreements

We try to use a custom component in the agreement modal in the checkout like by including the following HTML (which works on CMS pages) into the agreement block:

```
<div class="agreements js-accordeon" data-mage-init='{"simple-accordeon": ""}'>
```

But the component is not initialized.

I guess this is because the modal is generated by JS components as well.

Is there a *right*, yet *simple* way to do run a custom javascript in the agreement modal at the end of the checkout?

**EDIT**
The widget looks like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    $(".js-accordeon").addClass("is-active");
    $(".js-accordeon-trigger").each(function(){
        var element = $(this);

        element.click(function(){
            element.toggleClass("is-current");
            element.nextAll(".js-accordeon-target").eq(0).toggleClass("is-current");
            console.log(element.nextAll(".js-accordeon-target")[0]);
        });
    });
});
```

And it is working on other CMS pages, just not in the checkout's modal popup.

Comment: have you created your widget with `simple-accordeon` for that?

Comment: Yes, the widget is basically created. On CMS pages it works. But I did not create it in the checkout additionally - or what do you mean? @kunj

Comment: I mean jQuery widget, Can you share full code? I am not getting you.

Comment: edited my question